# Competition can be raised

Tags: passive-voice, collocations

Competition can be raised.

I want to say a sense of competition should be encouraged in children but I'm not sure if "competition" can be used with "raised".

Is it correct?

It is not just a matter of collocation.

I know we say "Raise sth" and "sth rises" but when do we use the passive form of "raise"?

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: I'm trying to say that a sense of competition should be encouraged in children and I was wondering if I could use this collocation instead.

Comment: I wouldn't use *raise* in this context. You may mean *increase* or *awaken.* Moreover, you seem to be saying that it's not "competition" which is increased/awakened but a "sense of competition", by which you probably mean something like the desire to compete. People sometimes use "competitiveness" for that, but these days that word more often means "ability to compete". I'd go with "The desire to compete can be awakened/increased".

Comment: However, you can say *the idea of competition can be raised*, as a topic of discussion. There are a few things that can be "raised," as in put forth for consideration, in this manner: ideas, points, objections, concerns, and so on. If you want to say that you are encouraging more competition, you'd need to use another verb, such as stressed, emphasized, encouraged or suggested. If you want to say that you want students to compete more, increased is probably the best word, or you can use one of StoneyB's improvements.